# How to select multiple avg(column) in one select statement in MySql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I find when I select one avg(column) into a variable,it is OK.But when I select  more than one avg into a variable,it is wrong.I do not want to write it twice,how to fixed it?

```
   //work well
  SELECT 
  avg(MathPoint) into  MathPoint 
 from student
 where  sex=1

 SELECT 
  avg(EnglishPoint) into  EnglishPoint
 from student
 where  sex=1

//do not work 
  SELECT  
 avg(EnglishPoint) into  EnglishPoint,
 avg(MathPoint) into  MathPoint,
 from student
 where  sex=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error on `INTO` usage.

`INTO` should follow all variable names together after selecting fields.

**Example**:

```
SELECT  
       avg(EnglishPoint), avg(MathPoint)
  into EnglishPoint, MathPoint
  from student
 where  sex=1
```

**Documentation**:

- [SELECT ... INTO Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

  - `SELECT ... INTO var_list` selects column values and stores them into
    variables.